# Проблема со взаимодействием Python и С++: could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"

Tags: c++, python, pyqt5, matplotlib

Добрый день. Начал изучение Python и столкнулся с проблемой, в сопряжении С++ и python 3.6.

Задача заключается в следующем: необходимо разработать ПО на С++ которое будет взаимодействовать с скриптами python, выполняя необходимые вычисления и отображать их на графиках. Для вычисления использую numpy, а для отображения matplotlib.

Используемые компоненты:

```
VS 2017, компилятор msvс.
Набор Anaconda3, c python 3.6
ОС: Win10 x64
```

Возникла проблема что когда пытаешься использовать инструкцию:

```
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt;
import numpy as np;
x = np.arange(1, 200, 0.0001)
plt.plot(x,x**2)
```

Возникает ошибка:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"
in "".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

Понимаю что проблема заключается в том, что PyQt5 используемый в matplotlib не видит каталога plugins/platforms/*.dll, но вообще не понимаю как заставить его увидеть.

Пробовал:

- Копировать каталог plugins в каталог с программой на C++
- Копировать каталог plugins в каталог с интерпретатором python
- Прописывать пути в sys.path и os.path

При этом, когда работаю из среды PyCharm, то "всё хорошо". Никаких проблем не возникает. Подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: в QTCreator попробуй

Comment: А чём разница будет ?

Comment: У вас есть в пути к директории с Anaconda не-ASCII символы?

Comment: Вероятнее всего нет

Comment: В данный момент я вообще захардкодил вручную все пути, прописав их через API PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.insert(0,\"C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\") \n");

Comment: создайте минимальный но полный пример кода (c++ + python), который ошибку воспроизводит [mcve]

Comment: Спасибо всем. Разобрался.
Как всегда всё из-за не внимательности. 
Как оказалось у меня на системе было установлено два python 3.6.
Один из них входил в состав anaconda, а другой отдельно.
При вызове скрипта в переменной sys.path, путь к PyQt5 отсутствовал.
Помогло добавление пути командой sys.path.insert().

Если кому поможет, так же прилагаю пример сопряжения C++ и Python.

https://github.com/Frogee/PythonCAPI_testing

Comment: если думаете что нашли решение, то можно его как ответ опубликовать—это [явно приветствуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброго времени суток. Прошу прощения за столь долгую задержку между вопросом и ответом. Проблема была на поверхности.
Как оказалось у меня на системе было установлено два python 3.6.
При вызове скрипта в переменную `sys.path` путь к PyQt5 отсутствовал. Помогло добавление соответствующего пути командой `sys.path.insert()`.
Для людей начинающих изучение python, опубликую алгоритм настройки окружения, а так же тестовый пример.

1. Устанавливаем интерпретатор python 3.6 (Anaconda) https://www.anaconda.com/download/
2. При установке указываем необходимость записи данных в переменную среды `PATH`
3. После установки в создаём переменную среды `PYTHONPATH` и прописываем в неё пути по которым будут расположены библиотеки и модули, а так же те каталоги в которых вы хотите размещать собственные скирпты.

   Пример(PYTHONPATH):

   ```
   ..\Anaconda3;
   ..\Anaconda3\Lib;
   ..\Anaconda3\Scripts;
   ..\Anaconda3\DLLs;
   ..\Anaconda3\Library\bin;
   ..\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages;
   ```

Пример взаимодействия c++ и python 2.7: https://github.com/Frogee/PythonCAPI_testing

Пример взаимодействия c++ и python 3.6: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html

Удачи !!! 
P.S. Если я где-то не прав, прошу корректировать