# Ошибка this application failed to start because no qt platform plugin could be initialized.Reinstalling the application may fix this problem

Tags: python, pyqt

Помогите,возникает ошибка при запуске дизайна проги из pycharm.
this application failed to start because no qt platform plugin could be initialized.Reinstalling the application may fix this problem

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from designporgi1 import Ui_MainWindow
import sys

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = ExampleApp()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()  # Показываем окно
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Этот код тоже не работает,возникает такая же ошибка.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


if __name__ == '__main__':
     app = QApplication(sys.argv)

     w = QWidget()
     w.resize(250, 150)
     w.move(300, 300)
     w.setWindowTitle('Simple')
     w.show()

     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768871/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-python-%D0%B8-%D0%A1-could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform    https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/744170/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-this-application-failed-to-start-because-it-could-not-find-or-load-the

Comment: и https://forum.qt.io/topic/90293/could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-plugin-windows-in

Answer (score 1):

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from designporgi1 import Ui_MainWindow


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):     # <--- + Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = ExampleApp()                   # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()                           # Показываем окно
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**designporgi1.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(344, 301)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 90, 101, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 90, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 344, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button_2"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё равно возникает.

Comment: Запустите программу из командной строки. Какой результат?

Comment: Опубликуйте `designporgi1.py`

Comment: Даже новый код который я привел не работает.Возникает такая же ошибка.

Comment: `Запустите программу из командной строки !!!`  Какой результат ????

Comment: ничего не изменилось.

Comment: qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "windows" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initiali
zed. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem. Это если запускать из командной строки.

Comment: С вашим новым кодом возникает такая же ошибка.